# how to fetch page content of an URL Request (post)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a little Mac application which should be able to post Data to my web server which saves the data in a database. Now that's the Code I have now:

```
NSData *postData = [urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (connection) NSLog(@"Done");
```

And it works fine. But now I want to check whether the data was correct (and stored in the database) or something (like eMail) is wrong. The PHP file prints e.g. "email incorrect" out if the E-Mail is not correct.
But how can I fetch this data (which PHP prints out) in Xcode that the App knows whether it was successful or not?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the delegate method for the NSURLConnection,

<del>- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response.

This method is called by the app when the request finishes. You can access response data using the 'response' parameter.</del>

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
```

Then just convert the 'data' parameter into a string using:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then you can search the response for whatever string you want, e.g., "email incorrect".

PS: I generally don't use NSURLConnection/NSURLRequest for HTTP requests, I'd recommend you check out ASIHTTPRequest for really simple HTTP requests/connections.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer first, but how can I convert the response to a String?

Comment: See my edited answer. Sorry for the confusion. As I said, I haven't used NSURLRequest and suchlike in a while because of ASIHTTPRequest. Highly recommend you checking it out.

Comment: Ah yes thank you very much, it works! :)
That with ASIHTTPRequest i'll check out later, for this app I think this is also okay. What exactly is better with ASIHTTPRequest?

Comment: It allows you to do a whole host of functions that would take a long time using NSURLConnection. Something I found useful was network queues: I had a load of files I wanted to download and ASIHTTPRequest contains ASINetworkQueue to execute a list of request.

See this for examples:
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: Ok thanks! But I have another question: I have a textfield for the email. Now I want that the user doesn't have to enter it every time he starts the app, so is it possible to save this data? I think CoreData is not so good for that because its only one string.

Comment: Look into `NSUserNSUserDefaults` for saving the textfield value

Comment: Hm, I now have this code for the launch:
`NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *maild = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
    if(maild != nil) {
        [mail setStringValue:maild];
    }
` and this for saving: `NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:mailv forKey:@"mail"];` but doesn't work :(

Comment: Okay I already found what was wrong I changed the Key to something different. Mail was maybe too general.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods `connection:didReceiveData:` and `connectionDidFinishLoading:`

According to the docs  `didReceiveData:` may be called multiple times per NSURLRequest (i.e. the response will not always arrive all at once) so the recommended method is to append the incoming data to buffer during `connection:didReceiveData:` and then do any processing on the data in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`.

You could create a property on your class like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *dataBuffer;
```

And instantiate your buffer during `viewDidLoad:`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.dataBuffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    // do any other setup your class requires...    
}
```

And then implement the delegate methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // clear the buffer in case it has been used previously
    [self.dataBuffer setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.dataBuffer appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
    NSString *response = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[self.dataBuffer bytes]]); 
    NSLog(@"response from HTTP request=>%@", response);
}
```

This can all also be done using a third-party networking library like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) (which is no longer under active develoment) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), but sometimes those can be overkill depending upon what you are trying to accomplish